# Error occuring when trying to produce graph from other sheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of code, that *sometimes* produces an error.

**What the code does**

 The code takes a fixed range of values from another spreadsheet. Those values are then simply used to create a scatter graph. And the graph gets pasted onto the current worksheet.

**The Error Message**

[image: The error box I am getting]

The code is a Run-time error '-2147221504 (80040000)': The maximum number of data series per chart is 255.

Again, this error only *sometimes* gets produced. 

**The Code**

```
    Dim GraphRange As Range
    Dim cht As Shape

    Set GraphRange = Sheets("This Sheet").Range("V10:W8013")
    Set cht = Sheets("This Sheet").Shapes.AddChart2(, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers)

    With cht.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=GraphRange
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 1.5
        .ChartArea.Height = 520
        .ChartArea.Width = 400
        .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "The Graph"

    End With
```

The Code is called from another sub, however, I do not think the conditions in which it is called is the problem.

**EDIT**

 When this error occurs, for whatever reason, it is trying to take the values from the sheet that it is supposed to be pasting the graph on. Meaning it isn't even looking at the correct spreadsheet.

Comment: You probably need to set the _PlotBy_ argument when using `.SetSourceData` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Chart.SetSourceData

Comment: I will try that. I would just need to put plotBy:= xlcolumns there I think

Comment: It might actually be `xlRows` - I remember it being counterintuitive. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-how-rows-and-columns-of-data-are-plotted-in-a-chart-2be5cea4-715a-4637-9a67-73b99c8dc5e7

Comment: well it is working for now. if I get the error again, I will change it and update :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `xlRows` - from the [XlRowCol Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrowcol), `xlRows` is used when the "Data series is in a column"

Comment: I changed it to xlRows, but I never got an error from xlcolumns

Comment: "To notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith"

Comment: @BigBen see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been working for me so far... I PlotBy:=xlColumns in .SetSourceData

```
Sub CreateGraph()

Dim GraphRange As Range
Dim cht As Shape

Set GraphRange = Sheets("This Sheet").Range("V10:W8013")
Set cht = Sheets("This Sheet").Shapes.AddChart2(, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers)

    With cht.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=GraphRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 1.5
        .ChartArea.Height = 520
        .ChartArea.Width = 400
        .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "My Graph"

    End With
End Sub
```